# Unable to install libsdl2-dev due to unmet dependencies

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to install libsdl2-dev unsuccessfully. I have searched Google and followed several answers on this site and more. I tried to reduce my repositories to just safe ones, have run apt-get update, apt-get upgrade.. and so many other things I cant exactly remember now. I've tried all I could find on Google. Here is the output I am getting from

```
sudo apt-get -f install libsdl2-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsdl2-dev : Depends: libudev-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse restricted universe main
deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse restricted universe main #Added by software-properties
```

and

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/youtube-dl-gui/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/youtube-dl-gui/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/youtube-dl-gui/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/youtube-dl-gui/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main

# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main

deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main

# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main
```

I have also tried

```
y-ppa-manager
```

and

```
synaptic
```

When I try to install libsdl2-dev using synaptic, first there are no broken packages, but then when I mark libsdl2-dev for installation, it says that I have to first remove broken packages. I have tried to apt-get remove --purge libsdl2-dev but since it is not installed it cannot be removed.

I appreciate any and all help. Thank you. I am post output for commands you give me and will remain active on this question until it can be resolved. Thank you again

EDIT 1:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu4) but 229-4ubuntu6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install 229-4ubuntu6
E: Unable to locate package 229-4ubuntu6
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1
libudev1 is already the newest version (229-4ubuntu6).
```

EDIT 2:

for the commands

```
 sudo add-apt-repository XXXXX
```

i always got

```
XXXXX distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

the rest as follows

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Reading package lists... Done                         
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libudev-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

FINAL EDIT:

This problem is now resolved. The finals steps to my solution were to enable the xenial-security and xenial-update repo's. After I did that and tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade I had soem errors downloading some updates. After this I changed my download server to the Main server and re-ran update & upgrade, which completed successfully. After this I was ale to successfully install libsdl2-dev. Thank you to doug and ali76 for their help!

Comment: see what's preventing libudev-dev from being installed

Comment: please see edits. i'm off work now but i'll be back tomorro to update

Comment: You have disabled both xenial-security & xenial-updates repos. Why people do that is beyond me. So re-enable both, update your sources & you should be fine. (- the latest version of libudev1, libudev-dev in 16.04 is 229-4ubuntu17

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it again

Comment: Run `software-properties-gtk` & under the Updates tab make sure both are enabled. If they are then under the Ubuntu Software tab pick another server, try Main server.

Comment: See my final update. This issue is now resolved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try this command:

> sudo apt-get install 229-4ubuntu6
>
> E: Unable to locate package 229-4ubuntu6

Because there isn't any package with `229-4ubuntu6` name in repositories.

The apt output says

> libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu4) but 229-4ubuntu6 is to be installed

That means , the `229-4ubuntu6` version of `libudev1` has been installed yet but the `229-4ubuntu4` version is required.

And the other things is that, the last version of `libudev1` for `xenial` is `229-4ubuntu17` but your apt returns the last version is `229-4ubuntu6`. This issue is happened because of that, many Ubuntu's repositories is disabled on your system and your repositories is not updated.

So as the first step we try to enable all of your Ubuntu repositories with this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Then update your repositories and your packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then try to fix broken packages:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

And as the last step try to install `libsdl2-dev` package:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
```

---

**Update:** Please add this lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

And comment this lines:

```
deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse restricted universe main
deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse restricted universe main #Added by software-properties
```

And then try this commands to update repositories and packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then try to install it again:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
```

Comment: libudev1 is an essential part of Ubuntu, so trying to remove it will either suggest to uninstall most of your operating system or just fail.

Comment: @lwho Thanks for your attention i've remove that part from my answer

Comment: Fortunately, both variants would just have refused to remove the package (I tried it with the "--dry-run" flag).

Comment: @lwho Thanks for your reply I've remove the last section of my answer

Comment: @A.Teator I've updated my answer please try it again

Comment: as from doug's comment above I have re-added xenial-updates and xenial-security repo's and after sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade, there are a ton of things that are currently downloading and upgrading. time remaining for downloads is approximately 55 minutes. i will update on the outcome as soon as it's finished and i try again to install libsdl2-dev

Comment: See my final update. This issue is now resolved. Thank you for your help!